# How can I generate an image where each pixel is a random color in R?

Tags: r

I would like to create an image consisting of randomly coloured pixels in R. I've got an input vector

```
colors <- as.data.frame(cbind(
    R = sample(0:255, 100, replace = T),
    G = sample(0:255, 100, replace = T),
    B = sample(0:255, 100, replace = T)))
```

that has 100 randomly generated colors. How can I generate an image with 10x10 pixels that refer to my color vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've previously solved a *similar* problem using the `grid` package (which is the base package that other packages like ggplot2 use to produce plots).

This is a very low-level package in R, so it is kind of creating the plot by hand, but it is a lot of fun in my opinion. Here is the code with comments

```r
# This function creates a grid that is represented by the units from 0 to 1
# in "npc" units, which is "natural parent coordinate" units. Basically (0, 0)
# is bottom-left, (1, 1) is top right.
make_grid = function(rows, cols) {
  lines_rows = grid::unit((0:rows) / rows, "npc")
  lines_cols = grid::unit((0:cols) / cols, "npc")
  return(list("row" = lines_rows, "col" = lines_cols))
}
# Create a 8x8 grid, i.e. 64 rectangles (squares in this case).
rows = 8
cols = 8
g = make_grid(rows, cols)

# Compute the center of each square in the grid. 
# We will be placing squares of color on top of this centers.
centers_rows = g$row[-1] - grid::unit(1 / (rows * 2), "npc")
centers_cols = g$col[-1] - grid::unit(1 / (cols * 2), "npc")

# for example, x_coords[1], y_coords[1] is the center of the rectangle on the bottom-left
# 
x_coords = rep(centers_cols, each = rows)
y_coords = rep(centers_rows, cols)

# Generate the random colors. Each row represents a rectangle. 
# Columns are R, G and B.
colors = matrix(data = sample(0:255, rows * cols * 3), rows * cols, 3)

# Now plot it!
# Open a new graph device
grid::grid.newpage()

# Fill it with a white background.
grid::grid.rect(gp = grid::gpar(col = NULL, fill = "white"))

# Push an empty viewport, basically an area we can plot.
grid::pushViewport(grid::viewport())

# Iterate over the rows of the matrix of colors.
for (r in 1:(rows * cols)) {
  # The positions of each rectangle are given by x_coords and y_coords
  grid::grid.rect(
    x = x_coords[r],
    y = y_coords[r],
    height = grid::unit(1 / rows, "npc"),
    width = grid::unit(1 / cols, "npc"),
    # This is a gpar that has no border color and fill given by the RGB 
    # we sampled above. 
    # I'm adding an alpha level because it looks better in my opinion.
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = NA,
      fill = rgb(colors[r, 1], colors[r, 2], colors[r, 3], alpha = 200, maxColorValue = 255)
    )
  )
}
```

And you have something like this

[image]

**UPDATE** I've used 8x8 grid, but you can use 10x10 grid with no problem.